# WPF Datagrid Datatemplate column with textboxes firing multiple change events

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, textbox

I'm using wpf datagrid for editing sales entries like quantity, discount, etc. I'm using DataTemplateColumn for each editable columns and textbox control inside each column. Each textbox is bound to a different column of the DataTable. While editing quantity, I have to calculate the net amount and update that column, which is done by updating the datatable bound to the grid. Handling everything inside `textchanged`, `lostfocus`, `gotfocus`, etc of each editable textbox. The datagrid selection unit is set to "Cell".

Now lots of issues are occurring while using this method. Sometimes the `textchanged` event of textbox inside templatecolumn is firing multiple times which makes all calculations wrong.

Can anybody tell what is the best method to edit a grid using datatemplate column? I have to use textbox itself because we have a number pad control which supports only textboxes. Why are the `textchanged` events firing multiple times? This happens even when we scroll the grid vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You could set UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged on the textboxes and use [RowEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending.aspx) to be sure that the user is actually done typing.

By default DataGrid won't commit changes until the editing row loses focus. Furthermore TextChanged fires when the TextBox control is created and initially populated with text.

I guess the TextChanged is fired when you scroll because the virtualization is kicking in, the DataGrid is recycling the rows to present the new objects and the text is actually changing on each cell.